# Updating AngularJS $scope variable after a successful $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, frontend

I have a simple controller and a simple `$http.post` call like so:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
var dataShuff = [];
myApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
        var cookieArr = [];
        $http.post(serverURL, input).then(function (response) {
            $scope.dataShuff = dataShuff = response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataShuff.length; i++) {
                if (typeof cookieArr[dataShuff[i].cookieID] === "undefined") {
                    cookieArr[dataShuff[i].cookieID] = [];
                }
                cookieArr[dataShuff[i].cookieID].push(dataShuff[i]);
            }
            $scope.dataShuff = cookieArr;
        }, function (response) {
            console.log('error ' + response);
        });
    }]);
```

The `$scope` variable `dataShuff` is updated once when the request completes but after I make some modifications via a `for` loop and reassign the variable, the same is not getting update on my view via `{{ dataShuff }}`

`console.log($scope.dataShuff);` is printing out the correct data.  As per other SO answers and elsewhere, I tried `$scope.$apply` and `$scope.applyAsync` and even `$timeout` but still got nowhere.

How do I get the `dataShuff` variable to update on the view?

P.S. I have omitted the `serverURL` and `input` variables as the API endpoints belong to my organisation and are not public.

**UPDATE**

Interestingly enough, replacing `var cookieArr = []` with `var cookieArr = {}` solves the problem.

View:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl"><pre> {{ dataShuff }} </pre><pre> {{ dataShuff | json }} </pre><div class="" ng-repeat="visit in dataShuff"><pre>  {{ visit | json }} </pre></div></div>
```

Comment: Why do you assign $scope.dataShuff to response.data when you're going to overwrite it and assign it to cookieArr down below? Also show us the view, so we can see how you are displaying it.

Comment: @MarkS.Just so that the view has something to display while the loop is running. Not really anything. It was just to check whether my `$http.post` is working. I am using a simple `{{ dataShuff }}` on the view as mentioned in the question.

Comment: The time that loop takes to run is insignificant, unless you are having a shitload of data.

Comment: $scope.dataShuff is an array and therefore `{{dataShuff}}` will show nothing. Perhaps you will get something displayed with a ng-repeat loop or by directly accessing the data through something like `{{dataShuff[0].yourvar}}`

Comment: Trying that. Will update.

Comment: @yBrodsky about 500 array elements.

Comment: @JanP `{{ dataShuff }}` is actually showing `[]` in the browser. An empty array.

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of the view ? Do you confirm that if you put `console.log($scope.dataShuff)` just after `$scope.dataShuff = cookieArr;` it logs some content ?

Comment: @AbbéRésina Indeed it does! My view is nothing more than `{{ dataShuff | json }}`. I even have a vanilla `{{ dataShuff }}`. I had some breakthrough from one of my colleagues at work. Updating question accordingly.